# jQuery to retrieve value of input array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the value of `input[name="color_cost[0]"]`

I have a jQuery script like this but the colorCost object is `undefined`

```
var colorCost = $('input[name="color_cost[0]"]').val();
```

```js
var colorCost = $('input[name="color_cost[0]"]').val();
console.log(colorCost);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="color_cost[]" value="100">
<input type="text" name="color_cost[]" value="200">
<input type="text" name="color_cost[]" value="300">
<input type="text" name="color_cost[]" value="300">
```

Comment: the `0` in the selector won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `0` changes the selector. Use `.eq(index)` to get the one you want.

```js
var colorCost = $('input[name="color_cost[]"]').eq(0).val();
console.log(colorCost);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="color_cost[]" value="100">
<input type="text" name="color_cost[]" value="200">
<input type="text" name="color_cost[]" value="300">
<input type="text" name="color_cost[]" value="300">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong selector if you put `0` between the brackets, it should be `'input[name="color_cost[]"]'`, it will give you a collection of elements.

```
var colorCost = $($('input[name="color_cost[]"]')[0]).val();
console.log(colorCost);
```

Then with `$('input[name="color_cost[]"]')[0]`  you can get the first one, and wrap it inside `$()` so it's read as jQuery object, and you can use `.val()` with it.

---

And if you want to get all the inputs values in an `array`, you can use:

```
var inputs = Array.from($('input[name="color_cost[]"]')).map(function(input){
    return $(input).val();
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var colorCost = $($('input[name="color_cost[]"]')[0]).val();
console.log(colorCost);

var inputs = Array.from($('input[name="color_cost[]"]')).map(function(input) {
  return $(input).val();
});
console.log(inputs);
console.log(inputs[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="color_cost[]" value="100">
<input type="text" name="color_cost[]" value="200">
<input type="text" name="color_cost[]" value="300">
<input type="text" name="color_cost[]" value="300">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.serializeArray()`

You don't need to specify `input` in the selector neither (if unique)

```js
var colorCost = $('[name="color_cost[]"]').eq(0).val();
var colorCostArray = $('[name="color_cost[]"]').serializeArray()

console.log(colorCost)
console.log(colorCostArray[0].value)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="color_cost[]" value="100" size="3">
<input type="text" name="color_cost[]" value="200" size="3">
<input type="text" name="color_cost[]" value="300" size="3">
<input type="text" name="color_cost[]" value="300" size="3">
```